# HTML5 constraint validation translation with Django

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, validation

I have some form that I am generating using the standard `django.forms.ModelForm`. When a required field isn't filled out, an HTML5 validation error is trigged (i.e., Please fill out this field, or Please lengthen this text to 200 characters or more (you are currently using 3 characters). However, the validation text is not translated, and I do not see it in my translations I've generated with `makemessages`. How could I make sure that these validation errors get appropriately translated?

Thanks,

Comment: HTML5 validations are not raised by Django and wouldn't be found in your translated message. If your message is not being translated, check that the HTML contains a language declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @DanielRoseman. I've added a language declaration on the root element via `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang ="es">`, but am still seeing validation errors in English. Is there another place where I should be declaring it as well?

Comment: Ah ok, so it looks like according to this link https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-set-up-the-language-of-a-form-html5 the HTML5 validations depend on the language set on your OS, rather than the language declaration on your HTML doc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set attributes of your input field to use oninvalid attribute with setCustomValidity('Your translated message.') value.

I will post example here for email validation with translated strings by ugettext_lazy for your input field.

First in your forms define email field (in similar way to this):

```
contact_email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
                                attrs={ 'class':'form-control',
                                        'placeholder':_('YOUR_EMAIL'),
                                        'max_length':30,
                                        'oninvalid':_('CUSTOM_VALIDITY'),
                                        'onchange':"setCustomValidity('')",}),
                                label=_('YOUR_EMAIL_LABEL_TAG'),
                                help_text=_('YOUR_EMAIL_TAG_HELP'),
                                required=True)
```

Now you need to translate your strings, all translations are straight forward except CUSTOM_VALIDITY which need to be jQuery with translation.

Go to your .po files and find lines with:
`msgid "CUSTOM_VALIDITY"`
and set msgstr to this:

```
msgstr ""
"if(this.validity.typeMismatch){this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address!');}"
"else{this.setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field.');}"
```

Translate these two messages to your language:
Please enter a valid email address!
Please fill out this field.'

Don't forget to include this line on top:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```